# Bash if else statement syntax error

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

So I have this little problem. I'm not sure where it went wrong because I'm pretty sure I got the code right.
Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
playerHP=100
echo "Hello World"
echo "HP: $playerHP"
echo "Continue? (Y/N):"
read -p $confirm
if [ "$confirm" = "y" ]
then
    echo "Yes"
elif [ "$confirm" = "n" ]
then
    echo "No"
else
    echo "No such command"
fi
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net will point you to the problem

Comment: The code you post in your question is different from the code in the error message. Hint: missing quotes.

Comment: The code you posted does not conform to the code you are running. You posted `[ "$confirm" = "n" ]` (good!), but the error message implies `[ $confirm == "n" ]` (bad).

Answer (score 5):

Unrelated: `read` needs a prompt after `-p`. Blend the previous `echo` into it, and while at it, remove the `$` from the variable name there.

```
read -p "Continue? (Y/N):" confirm
```

The error message is confusing. Don't you have MSWin line ends in the script?

Comment: It's more than "while at it" : with the `$` the `$confirm` variable is expanded to the empty string before the `read` builtin is run and the user input is lost.

Comment: The rule is that `$variablename` is used to *get* the value of the variable; when *setting* a variable (in an assignment, with `read`, whatever) just use the plain variable name without the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have modified your script below use it. Working fine for me

```
#!/bin/bash
playerHP=100
echo "Hello World"
echo "HP: $playerHP"
read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm
echo $confirm

if [ "$confirm" = "y" ]
then
    echo "Yes"
elif [ "$confirm" = "n" ]
then
    echo "No"
else
    echo "No such command"
fi
```

Comment: These are the errors I get:
': not a valid identifier: `confirm

gametest.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
gametest.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'ametest.sh: line 11: `elif [ "$confirm" = "n" ]

Comment: can you just execute this line in your command prompt and let me know `if [ "y" = "y" ]; then  echo "correct"; fi` and `if [ "y" == "y" ]; then  echo "correct"; fi`.

Comment: gametest.sh: line 7: $'\r'... RC windows?

Comment: change this line `#!/bin/bash`  to `#!/bin/ksh`